# How to create templates that update template-based files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm moving my web project from Dreamweaver to Visual Studio Code and after spending many hours going through the available extensions in the Market Place, I have not been able to find one that updates template-based files when the template is edited.

Some of the extensions that I tried:
File Templates VSCode Extension,
Template Generator,
Volt: Template Engine,
code-template-replace

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also have an old project based on Dreamwaver templates and I would like to carry on with Visual Studio Code. Finding no solutions I reinstalled Dreamwaver :-(